# Django: Does not raise error if CharField and TextField are not provided

Tags: django, django-models

In Django model fields by default `blank=False` and `null=False`

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Now i try to save Test without supplying name

```
Test.objects.create(pk=1)
```

Now i am expecting it should raise an exception `"null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint"` saying that name is required. Whereas for other fields it will raise an exception that we have to provide the value

So is it some default behaviour for CharField and TextField that will allow to store empty string irrespective of blank and null, if we try to save a model directly without any forms.

Answer (score 0):

Something else is wrong.

`CharField` is [required to define a 'max_length' attribute.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField)
`Test` should not have made it past `makemigrations`, yet alone get to the stage of creating objects. Did you remember to run a migration? I ran into that error testing this.

Here is the raw SQL query which Django is running (assuming you add the max_length and makemigrations):

`'INSERT INTO "polls_test" ("id", "name") SELECT 4, \'\'', 'time': '0.007'`

Apparently Django takes it upon itself to just set name to blank if you create it deliberately with `.create()`.

One thing I did find is that [Django specifically wants `null` to be avoided in CharField and TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null), with instead an empty string being the empty value. This is probably a side effect of that decision.

Comment: `Apparently Django takes it upon itself to just set name to blank if you create it deliberately with .create().`.  So its a slight risk because it does not warn about empty string.

Comment: No. I assume that you would either need to check for that yourself or use `null` with CharField.

Comment: ` or use null with CharField`  - what does this mean

Comment: You can presumably allow `Charfield` to use null, which would generate the warning about it being empty.

Comment: you mean `models.CharField(NULL=TRUE)`.

Comment: Yep. That seems to be your main option if you want the warning

Comment: I dont think it will warn. Warning is only give if `NULL=False`. I think when using create() there is no way to avoid Charfield or TextField not being empty. Because null=False will not work. NULL=False is the only way to warn when using create() for other fields. Am i true. Only way is to always use forms and not create() in such cases.